# Detect memory leak when placement new is used using sanitizer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

How force sanitiser to detect memory leaks when memory allocation takes place in a predefined storage?
Below an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class A
{

};
typename std::aligned_storage<256, alignof(256)>::type store;
A * foo()
{
    return  new (&store) A();
}
A * bar()
{
    return  new  A();
}
int main() {
    A * a = foo();
    a     = foo();

    A * a2 = bar();
    a2 = bar(); 
}
```

When bar is called memory leak is detected.
But no when foo is called
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7j1Ts83Eo)

Comment: That is not a memory leak, A doesn't allocate anything on the heap, also A is POD ... so that's not even UB.

Comment: I don't think it's technically memory leaks that you're trying to detect here. Perhaps you're trying to detect resource clobbering due to the re-use of `store` for multiple instances of `A`. I think that would be more in the realm of strict aliasing violation.

Comment: you seem to confuse allocation of memory with creating the objects. Usually you do the two together, but here you only create an object in already preallocated memory. Your code misses to call the destructors, but thats not a memory leak

Comment: IMHO that's just bad code that asan isn't going to guard against, you aren't corrupting the heap, you are corruptting the stack/static storage, instead you want something like a memory pool resource on top with unique pointers to manage the lifetime of objects and guarantee the same memory won't be used twice.

Comment: i am not sure what answer this questions needs. Are you looking for an explanation why there is no memory leak from calling `foo`? Or are you already aware that it is not memory that is leaked and are looking for a way to detect this pattern (which is not a leak, and not an issue in this simple example, but might be elsewhere) ?

Comment: I am aware that this is not a memory leak. I am looking for a pattern how to detect a memory leak when a predefined storage is used.

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to detect that it was forgotten to destroy the object. You are not looking "how to detect a memory leak" because there is no leak from calling `foo`

Comment: ...or perhaps you refer to resources managed by `A` that are not shown in the code here?

Comment: So the question is about avoiding multiple initialization while devicing lazy initialization. That's a difficult one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` is "trivially destructible", which means (quote taken from cppref docs for [`std::is_trivially_destructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_destructible)):

> Storage occupied by trivially destructible objects may be reused without calling the destructor.

Moreover, there is no memory leak from calling `foo` several times, because `foo` itself does not allocate any memory.

This code is totally fine and there is no reason for a sanitzier to complain:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class A
{

};
typename std::aligned_storage<256, alignof(256)>::type store;
A * foo()
{
    return  new (&store) A();
}
int main() {
    A * a = foo();
    a     = foo();
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_destructible<A>::value;
}
```

[Output is](https://godbolt.org/z/zaP1M7vcE)

```
 1
```